# Various ways to identify smoked foods and liquid smoke

Tags: flavor, texture, smoking, tasting, smoke-flavor

What are some key identifiers for telling if a dish was smoked manually rather than using liquid smoke i.e. taste, smell, visually etc.

I'm curious about meats, veggies etc.

What I already know:

(in meats with fat) is the noticeable colour gradients differing in fats on meat that implies a wood fire smoke.

A single note char/musty smell usually hints towards a liquid smoke.

Typically smoked foods impart various smells and flavours that'll penetrate inside the dish rather than a liquid smoke.